# Information on the new Death Star

Tags: star-wars

Is there any additional information, such as price, piece count, appearance or minifigures for the upcoming LEGO death star? Leaked, announced or rumored answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information available as of today is the set number. It is #75159. No other rumors or leaked info is available. The speculation is that it will likely be based on the new movie, but even this is simply a speculation, not even a rumor.

Comment: Based on the new movie? Rouge One?

Comment: Darn. I thought there might be a rumour I had not yet heard. Oh well, I suppose I'll have to wait.

Comment: Caleb, no, The Force Awakens. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: But... There is no Death Star in FA... That's a (hacked) planet!

Comment: I've heard the Starkiller base rumours as well, but I don't think it would make sense for Lego to reveal it as a Death Star if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's an update of the previous minifigure-based Death Star, according to reliable hints.  It certainly is not a pure UCS model Death Star as many have hoped for.